# "L'on" against "on" which one is more accurate ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions, articles

"Si l'on me joue queque notes de piano.....ect"

does the l in "l'on" replace the subject, if yes what is this subject? 
does "on" in this case more correct? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @Feelew yes you are right have i delete this question or what i should do ?

Comment: Nothing, we keep duplicates as pointers to the place where the answers can be found (and updated).